# How to pass arguments on the command line when launching JAR?

Tags: java, jar, export, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to export my application to a JAR file. The program uses a lot of memory, so I used `-Xmx1500m` in Eclipse to make it work. It works when I export it (no errors), but it says VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. How can I add the `-Xmx1500m` to my application outside of Eclipse? I tried a batch file with `java -Xmx1500m` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
  java -jar yourJarName.jar arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Should I put this in a batch file?

Comment: @kneedhelp That's up to you, you could use a native executable wrapper if it fufilled your requirements

Comment: if you want - you can simply run this from a console